# How to Deserialize JSON string?

Tags: c#, deserialization

I am trying to create a model for the following JSON string which has dynamic columns as shown below

```
[{"DId":0,"DData":[{"Date":"","C0":{"D":"National","Id":"National"},"C1":{"D":"National","Id":"National"},"C2":{"D":"National","Id":"National"}},{"Date":"1/2/2010","C0":{"D":0.74,"Id":1334337,"Dirty":"False"},"C1":{"D":0.6,"Id":1334597,"Dirty":"False"},"C2":{"D":1,"Id":1334857,"Dirty":"False"}}]}]
```

As I have highlighted the columns (C*) they are dynamic for example I can have JSON as follows where I have just two columns

```
[{"DId":0,"DData":[{"Date":"","C0":{"D":"National","Id":"National"},"C1":{"D":"National","Id":"National"}},{"Date":"1/2/2010","C0":{"D":0.74,"Id":1334337,"Dirty":"False"},"C1":{"D":0.6,"Id":1334597,"Dirty":"False"}}]}]
```

***C0,C1,C2 .... are dynamic.***

I am trying to build a generic model to deserialize my JSON string.  Right now I have my model as follows

```
public class C0
{
    public object D { get; set; }
    public object Id { get; set; }
    public string Dirty { get; set; }
}

public class C1
{
    public object D { get; set; }
    public object Id { get; set; }
    public string Dirty { get; set; }
}

public class C2
{
    public object D { get; set; }
    public object Id { get; set; }
    public string Dirty { get; set; }
}

public class DData
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public C0 C0 { get; set; }
    public C1 C1 { get; set; }
    public C2 C2 { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public int DId { get; set; }
    public List<DData> DData { get; set; }
}
```

As I mentioned above distribution data can have dynamic columns. Any help I really appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to deserialize JSON yourself? Use [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx).

Comment: there are existing JSON libraries (NewtonSoft) you can use.

Comment: Your `C1, C2, ...` classes need to be turned into a `List<C>`, and use an array of objects in your Json. You can't dynamically create classes. (well, you can, but i'm not going to get into that...)

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, install the Web Tools to get access to "Paste Json As Classes" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc.aspx Then use Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize it.

Comment: @gunr2171 I thought of using List<C> and use an array of objects for Columns, but somehow my JSON is formatted correctly. So I gave up ...

Answer (score 0):

The secret is to keep your deserialized JSON in the most general form possible:

```
Dictionary<string, object> theData= new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);

System.Collections.ArrayList dData= (System.Collections.ArrayList)theData["DData"];

foreach (Dictionary<string, object> data in dData)
{
 string date = (string)data["Date"];

 Dictionary<string, object> cZeroNode = (Dictionary<string, object>)data["C0"];

 string d = (string)cZeroNode["D"];
 string id = (string)cZeroNode["Id"];
}
```

The call to `Deserialize()` creates a tree of `Dictionary<string, object>` that you can traverse at will.